# How to create a word document in docx form with terminal

Tags: bash

I know I can easily create a docx file with libreOffice, but I just want to learn more about using bash. Anyone able to explain if it is even possible with the terminal? The touch command does a decent job but it does not specify any extension.

Comment: File extensions don’t really matter in Ubuntu, so if you `touch file.docx` you have a docx file. :) What makes a docx file a docx file for you?

Comment: `touch` command lets you specify the extension; `touch foo.docx`, but that will create an empty file. Is that what you want? Otherwise, `loffice --convert-to docx foo.odt` will work in a terminal.

Comment: @dessert docx is a file format: [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)

Comment: "Anyone able to explain if it is even possible with the terminal?" FYI: odt, docx, xlsx are containers. You can gunzip them and have the human  readable version of it. Well human readable ... it is an xml and a large one.

Comment: If your objective is learn bash, this isn't a bash operation. Using 3rd party tools in bash isn't using bash. If you want to learn bash, try to combine 2 or more separate tools into something useful. You don't even need bash to do this.

Comment: @Braiam Calling the external tools from Bash is using Bash (like in my answer, I use a pipe), but you're right - any shell can do that.

Answer (score 30):

According to [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379999/117037) over at Unix & Linux, you can use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

From skimming [the documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), I think you could use it like:

```
echo "Hello" | pandoc -o out.docx
```

Then `out.docx` will be a docx file with "Hello" in it.

---

As well, I found this Python module: [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: +1 TIL about Pandoc, which in fact can convert [*a ton* of markup formats](https://pandoc.org/diagram.jpg) into each other.

Answer (score 22):

LibreOffice comes with a command-line tool called `soffice` which has `libreoffice` pointing to it, this tool has a `--convert-to` option which lets you easily convert files in the same way the GUI program does, e.g.:

```
libreoffice --convert-to docx file.txt
```

This creates the file `file.docx` in [Office Open XML Text format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) in the current directory.

#### Usage example

```
$ echo some text > file.txt
$ libreoffice --convert-to docx file.txt 

convert /home/dessert/file.txt -> /home/dessert/file.docx using filter : Office Open XML Text
$ file file.docx 
file.docx: Microsoft OOXML
```